# How do I create a buffered smooth animation with multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, buffer

I'm trying to do a simple program where a ball moves through a Canvas in a JFrame.
I want to have the main thread updating the position of the ball in the screen and printing each frame on the canvas, while another thread goes updating each next frame on a buffer. Here's my code:

```
public class SynchAnimation {

private JFrame frame;
private Canvas canvas;
private BufferedImage frameImage;
private Graphics bfg;
private final int width = 500, height = 500;
private int x, y;
private DrawingThread drawingThread;
private final Object key;

public SynchAnimation() {

    key = new Object();

    x = 200;
    y = 200;

    frame = new JFrame("Synchronized animation");
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frameImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bfg = frameImage.createGraphics();

    canvas = new Canvas() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(frameImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    canvas.setSize(width, height);

    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void mainRun() {

    drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
    drawingThread.start();

    while (true) {
        synchronized (key) {
            x += 1;
            y += 1;
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }
}

class DrawingThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (key) {
                bfg.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                bfg.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                bfg.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                bfg.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                bfg.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SynchAnimation().mainRun();
}
```

Why is it still flickering as hell? I thought the synchronized blocks would do the trick. This is not actually a GUI question, it's a threads question... I'm doing this to understand how synchronized threads work when trying to access and modify the same data.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm shocked that this even sorta works.   You don't start a thread to draw - you override the `paint()` and/or `update()` methods of your component.   The GUI toolkit is event-based and there is a structure to these applications.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html for an overview of Swing components / event flow / drawing.

Comment: Also, you should know that there is absolutely zero claim made by the language specification about the order in which threads get monitor locks (as from `synchronized` - it's perfectly valid behavior for one of your loops to never run at all, the way you've coded that.   Take an example project from the trail I linked and C&P to start, then modify from there.   Sample code is completely wrong. =/

Comment: As an additional comment what to use synchronzied for: To prevent simultanious access to a critial software part. While in that block a parallel access is not possible and thus nullifing any benefit you get from a seperate thread. Use them only around critial parts (for example: access a resource)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to override paintComponent() instead